# What spatial SRID is this? (trying to convert a .shp file to WSG84)

Tags: geospatial, spatial, srid

I'm trying to import some Shapefile mapping data into Sql2008. Before I do that, I need to convert it to `WGS84 / SRID 4326`, because all my existing data is in this format.

This is the source file info:

```
GEOGCS["GCS_GDA_1994",DATUM["D_GDA_1994",
    SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]
```

I've tried googling for this and haven't had too much luck.
Secondly, I've tried to check the `spatial_reference_systems` table and I can't see it in there.

eg. `SELECT * from sys.spatial_reference_systems`

So, can anyone help me? I can't covert it to `SRID 4326` if i don't know it's current SRID.

#### UPDATE 1

I found [this page](http://www.ga.gov.au/mapspecs/250k100k/appendix_m.jsp) which explains the tech specs of GDA 1994 .. but doesn't hint at any SRID number... ???

#### UPDATE 2

[This search result page](http://spatialreference.org/ref/?search=GCS_GDA_1994) also has some interesting results. From here, if you click on the [SR-ORG:6643: Australia Albers Equal Area Conic](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6643/) link, it explains that datum .. and it's pretty much identical to the one I'm searching for. This means the SRID is 6643.

So is that the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using FME as my reference, this (GDA94) maps to EPSG:4283, which means that you need to use SRID 4283 (assuming that you're using EPSG-compliant SRID values)

Comment: I think I ended up using 6643 ... but if FME say's it's 4283, then i'll roll with that :)

Answer (score 0):

Using [this link](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/28350/) GDA94 can be mapped to SRID = 4283 covering the Australian continent. If one knows, for example, that it is Western Australia it may be better to use SRID = 28350 and preserve greater accuracy.